# Array structure of raw SQL query results in CakePHP 3.8 / CakePHP 4 vs CakePHP 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-4.x

After CakePHP 4.0 has been released, we are considering to migrate our CakePHP 2.x application to 3.8 or 4.0. Currently, we are stuck with this issue:

Our application uses raw SQL statements sometimes using the [`Model::query()`](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) method.

---

For example, this **CakePHP 2** code:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.firstname FROM users u, contacts c WHERE u.id = 2 and c.id = u.contact_id";
$u = $this->User->query($sql);  // Or on any other model...
$this->log($u);
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [u] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [firstname] => MyFirstName
                )
            [c] => Array
                (
                    [zip] => 12345
                )

        )
)
```

---

When we try to do the same thing with **CakePHP 3.8**

```
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.firstname FROM users u, contacts c WHERE u.id = 1 and c.id = u.contact_id";
$u = $connection->execute($sql)->fetchAll();
$this->log($u);
```

the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => MyFirstName
            [2] => 12345
        )
)
```

---

In order to migrate safely: Is there a way to make CakePHP 3.8 / 4 return query results using the same array structure as in CakePHP 2?

Rewriting the statements to use ORM is not an option. The example above is not a real code - the real queries are more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements), you should be using `->fetchAll('assoc')`. The output of this isn't quite identical to what you had in Cake 2, but at least the field names are present.

Comment: The 2.x format is really ugly. If necessary for a step by step migration, one could implement something similar in 3.x/4.x, see the `DboSource::resultSet()` and `DboSource::fetchResult()` implementations in [**the 2.x database drivers**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/tree/2.10.19/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database).

Comment: Exactly. As I said, it's not identical, but the field names are there. Migrating from 2.x to 3.x is a major task.

Comment: Thanks @greg-schmidt .

When I use `->fetchAll('assoc')`, tough, the result looks like this:

`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [firstname] => MyFirstName
            [zip] => 12345
        )
)`

This contains the field names, but still misses the table aliases... 

@ndm It seems a bit too cumbersome to rewrite the 4.x database drivers in order to make this work. Maybe, we will just stick around with 2.x a little bit longer. Ugliness, just like beauty, is in the eye of the beholder... :-)

Comment: It's a shame you can't use the new ORM as it's intended to be used. It really is a thing of beauty.

Comment: @GregSchmidt My impression is that we would need to rewrite our entire application to adapt to the new ORM. Because the structure of the data object changed, this would apply not only the models, but also the controllers and views...

Comment: I agree with @GregSchmidt, the ORM is really good. Also for future updates, debugging, etc. I would recommend to consider using the ORM.